# Showing Steps of Calculations

Tags: differential-equations

I'm solving a a differential equation in Mathematica and was wondering how to show the steps, like how Wolfram|Alpha does it, in the program. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't believe Mathematica will do that on its own, but you can obtain the Wolfram|Alpha result (including step-by-step) like this: `WolframAlpha["solve (x+1) y'(x) + y(x) == x"]`

Comment: Thank You. It worked, just have to put how you'll input it into Wolfram|Alpha rather than the actual code to solve it.

Comment: WolframAlpha probably doesn't use the method it shows actually to solve differential equations under normal circumstances. The steps are most likely a separate calculation to show how one *could* solve it using elementary techniques, and this isn't implemented in *Mathematica*.